# i have created a login page on c# and i need to print welcome to my page when i enter username and password. How is it possible?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i have created a login page on c# and i need to print welcome to my page when i enter username and password. How is it possible?
This is the code currently
I want when a user is authorized I want to display a welcome message on main page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\NETCOM\OneDrive\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From Login where Username ='" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.Hide();
                Main ss = new Main();
                ss.("Welcome to my page");
                ss.Show();

           
               
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Please check your username and password ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have create a constructor over load in your main page. By which you can send welcome message in main page

```
 Main ss = new Main("Welcome to my page");               
 ss.Show();

public partial class Main: Form
{
  public Main(string msg="")
  {
    //declare a label in main from to show message 
    Label label1=new Label();
    label1.Text=msg;
  }
}
```